# How to collect a grep and use it in a aws configset

Tags: amazon-web-services, grep, yaml, aws-cloudformation

In my aws Cloud Formation cfn configset I have a command to set an environment key to the name of the user group apache belongs to as it might be apache or www-data depending on the distro.

Something like this:

```
Metadata:
  AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    configSets:
      joomla:
        - "set_permissions"
        - "and_some_more..."

    configure_cfn:
      files:
        /etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf:
          content: !Sub |
            [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
            triggers=post.update
            path=Resources.EC2.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
            action=/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -v --stack ${AWS::StackName} --resource EC2 --configsets joomla --region ${AWS::Region}
          mode: "000400"
          owner: root
          group: root
```

.....

```
    set_permissions:  
      commands:
        01_01_get_WebServerGroup:
          env:
          #webserver group might be apache or www-data depending on the distro
            WebServerGp: 
              command: "ps -ef | egrep '(httpd|apache2|apache)' | grep -v `whoami` | grep -v root | head -n1 | awk '{print $1}'"
```

However, when I launch this stack, the configsets process halts at this point and I get an an error in the cfn_init.log that looks like this:

> File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line
>   80, in apply
>       raise ToolError(u"%s does not specify the 'command' attribute, which is required" % name) ToolError: 01_01_get_WebServerGroup does
>   not specify the 'command' attribute, which is required

Is this the preferred method to catch and use a grep result in a configset command?  Is there a better way?  What can I do to address the error thrown in the cfn_init.log?

OK, I guess I can create parameter and mapping elements to capture the distro type on launch and then set the webserver group accordingly but I am really trying to understand how to set the env: key to a response from the cli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is this line `WebServerGp`.

Line `command` is must be on the same level of `env`, under the `commands` name, in your case is `01_01_get_WebServerGroup`. So, it has to be like this:

```
commands:
    01_01_get_WebServerGroup:
      env: ..
      command: ..
```

If you want to use the result of grep, you can put them on variable and use it later.
You can specify more than one command under that `command` line using `\n` for executing the command.

Please check this code below.

```
command: "result=(ps ef | grep ...)\n echo $result\n ..."
```

If you have really long command, you can use the `Fn::Join` to be the value of `command`.